# iPad Flash emulator

Tags: ipad, adobe-flash

I am using an Apple iPad. I have a number of programs that need Adobe Flash v10. Two of the programs have to do with my husband's business, accounting and load tracking. He is a trucker, I am his "bookkeeper".

Is there a program that emulates Flash? I am told that there is a *problem* between Apple and Adobe and Adobe will not allow iPad users to use Flash. This is really making me nuts.

Is there anything that I can use to get my work done?

Comment: It isn't Adobe that's not allowing you to use Flash on the iPad, it's Apple.

Answer (score 2):

There are apps that will allow you to run flash apps on a remote Mac, PC or server, and view the results on an iPad. RDP, VNC, and others.

Answer (score 2):

I have to disagree with [jhocking's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/12396/7833).  There *is* an app in the iOS app store called [iSwifter](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iswifter-flash-web-browser/id388857173?mt=8). From the description of the app:

> iSwifter Flash Browser unlocks your favorite Flash content on your iPad, letting you view videos, Flash websites, and best of all, interactive Flash applications...

I've used it and it works as advertised. However, it *only* works with the iPad. Also, the app is free, but there is a 10 (?) hour limit and after the 10 hours is up, you have to buy the "pro version" for $4.99.

Comment: Skyfire is not sufficient to answer the OPs question given the fact that it only works for video.

Comment: @JasonSalaz Sorry, I copied and pasted that answer from another one of my answers :-]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is not a way to run Flash on websites on the iPad.

There is technically a way to publish from Flash to an iOS app, but that's different from what you're asking. That's only relevant to people *making* apps, not people *using* the apps.

Answer (score 0):

There was, is and most likely never will be any way to run Flash on iOS. Apple [argued](http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/), Flash has too many performance problems, which is even more important on mobile devices with limited resources and battery. Until this day Adobe hasn't come up with a version of Flash which runs acceptable on mobile devices where it can be installed, like those running Android.

Even if Flash could be installed on iOS or if you would get an Android tablet, there is no guarantee you're able to use the Flash apps you want to use. All of them would have to be rewritten by the developer to support touch input. But [Adobe has abandoned Flash for mobile devices](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2011/11/adobe-mobile-flash-dead/) at the end of last year which makes it essentially a dead-end technology. So, I don't think any Flash developer will rewrite their apps to support touch input.

Your best bet is to look for alternatives of the Flash apps you've used, there are excellent accounting apps in the App Store.